# Consider a 1-tape TM that starts with n ≥ 1 written in unary/binary notation on its tape. Explain how it can count down from n to 0 in O(n) steps

Tags: time-complexity

> Consider a 1-tape TM that starts with n ≥ 1 written in unary/binary
> notation on its tape. Explain how it can count down from n to 0 in O(n) steps.

For binary notation, if we have a binary counter representing the number n, then will there be a total of O(log n) different bits (since each bit represents exponentially smaller and smaller values)?

Comment: The time complexity of the second part is heavily dependent on how you implement it. From what you write, each time you decrement the counter you spend $O(\log n)$ time (and, $\Omega(\log n)$ time for at least $\Omega(n)$ decrements) so the total time required is $\Theta(n \log n)$. However this doesn't solve the problem as it is too slow. To obtain a total time of $O(n)$ a more careful implementation and analysis is needed.

Comment: You mean I should find a better implementation that completes part b in O(n), and there actually exists one, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.$\phantom{}$

Comment: By the way, does the approach to complete the first part make sense?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I don't understand the whole thing about "printing"? A Turing machine doesn't print anything. Plus if "printing" a number with $x$ digits takes $O(x)$ time then, since the overall number of printed digits is $\sum_{i=0}^n i = \Omega(n^2)$, so is the required time. Apart from that, the strategy of deleting one $1$ at a time from one endpoint of the string works and decrements the counter from $n$ to $0$ in $O(n)$ steps.

Comment: It seems like that if we have a binary counter representing the number n (n-bits in binary), then there will be a total of O(log n) different bits. We know that O(log n) = O(n) in the Time Complexity theory, so it can count down from n to 0 in O(n) steps. What do you think about this logic?

Comment: I use Print to say the machine "enumerates" the string in the tape.

Comment: I don't understand that logic. It seems that by the same argument you'd be able to "count" down from $n$ to $0$ in $O(\log n)$ steps, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: I agree.. If you know the answer can you give me a hint to help think of an implementation that solves the problem in O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sketch of how you can solve the second part.
Suppose that the number $n$ is of the form $2^k - 1$ for some non-negative integer $k$ and that the head of the Turing Machine is initially located at the end of the binary representation of $n$ (i.e., at the position of the rightmost, least significant, bit).

Proceed as follows:

- While the current tape symbol is a $0$, replace it with $1$ and move the head to the left.
- If the current symbol is $1$:

  - Replace the current symbol with a $0$
  - Move right until you reach the last non-blank symbol of the tape
  - Repeat from the beginning
- Halt

In analyzing the time complexity, I will ignore the transitions that move right. This is because each of these transitions can be "charged" to a distinct transition that moved the head to the left, and we can safely ignore multiplicative constants in our asymptotic upper bound on the running time.

Notice how, once we ignore these transitions, at most a constant number of steps pass from the instant in which a TM flips a bit of the input tape, to the instant when the next bit flip happens. Then, to estimate the running time we can just count the overall number of bit flips.

Consider all values of $n$ from $2^k-1$ down to $0$, in this order.
The rightmost bit changes every time we move from one value to the next.
The 2nd to last bit changes every other time, the 3rd to last bit changes once every $4$ values, and so on.
In general, the $i$-th least significant bit changes once every $2^{i-1}$ values.

The total number of bit flips is then:
$$
n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \dots  = O\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{2^i}\right) = O(2^k) = O(n)
$$

Comment: What if n can be any number that can be written in binary notation (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,...,n)? You consider the case that n is 2^k-1. I wonder showing that the problem can be solved in O(n) using that partial case does really prove the general case of all binary representations. Can we apply this logic to the case when n is 14?

Comment: Also, when n is 7 (111 in binary), the process loops when n becomes 5 (101 in binary).

Comment: Yes, you can use it for any $n$ in time $O(n)$. I just gave you a sketch of the proof, you can fill in the details. The process does not loop when $n=5$. The next contents of the tape are $101 \to 100 (\to 101 \to 111) \to 011 \to 010 (\to 011) \to 001 \to 000$. The parts in brackets are the intermediate contents of the tape between two decrements.

Comment: How to make 5 using 2^k-1? In your logic, n must be 2^k-1, but there does not exist any non-integer k that makes n 5.

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, the same TM works for any $n$, whether it is of the form $2^k-1$ or not. The assumption $n=2^k-1$ is only used in the analysis of the time complexity and it does not affect the correctness. Regarding the time complexity, you can either be more careful in the calculations, or just argue as follows: consider the first integer $n'\ge n$ such that $n'=2^{k'}-1$ for some $k'$. The time spent for $n$ is asymptotically not larger than the one spent for $n'$. Since $n' =\Theta(n)$, the running time for $n$ is still $O(n)$. I'll let you figure out the details.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the binary representation of a number $n = (a_0a_1…a_{k-1}a_k)_2$ ($a_0$ being the least significant bit) written on the tape, then in order to decrement $n$ by one, you will have to do the converse of an increment:

- with $i$ starting at $0$, while $a_i = 0$, transform $a_i$ into $1$ and increment $i$;
- unless $n = 0$, you will find $i$ such that $a_i = 1$.

  - if $i = k$, then transform this $1$ into the blank symbol;
  - otherwise, transforme this $1$ into $0$.

Once you have done that, you can return to the left-most bit, and do it again, until you reach $0$.

Now to analyse the complexity: it seems that in the worst case, we will have to move the head of the Turing machine until the last bit of the input, and that may take $\Theta(\log n)$ steps. Since $n$ decrements are necessary, it looks like the total complexity is $\Theta(n\log n)$, but in reality the worst case for one decrement is not that often reached.

Actually, the necessary  steps for one decrement are equal to the number of consecutives $0$'s at the beginning of the tape ($\times 2$ since we have to return to the left-most bit). Now you just need to count $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n$(number of 0's at the beginning of k), and verify that it is $O(n)$.

Comment: Is k in “number of 0’s at the beginning of k” the string on each configuration? For example, when n = 4, k will be 001, 11, 01, 1.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: So, the total complexity is O(2n) -> O(n) because # of conesecutive 0’s at the beginning on every configuration is O(n) and retunring to the leftmost-bit is constant? But when n = 5, # of conesecutive 0’s does not match with n: 101, 001, 11, 01, 1 (3 * 2 steps). 6 or 3 is not equal to 5.

Comment: No, that's wrong… The number of $0$'s at the beginning of an integer $k$ is the $2$-adic order of $k$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). And the sum of $2$-adic orders of all integers from $0$ to $2^k-1$ is $O(2^k)$.